# Access web page from a different project

Tags: asp.net

NET ..

In my solution I have two projects and I need a access a webpage of a second project from my 1st project ..
Used

```
protected void registerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("./PersonalDetails/Details.aspx");
    }
```

where PersonalDetails is my second project...but no success

Answer (score 1):

Try HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/csweb/Default.aspx"). The tilde "~" in your current redirect says to start in this application's home folder. By removing that you can redirect to some other location on your site.

You can also fully qualify the redirect to go to an entirely different site if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Please Add In Web.config

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="PersonalDetails" value="http://localhost:9999/xx/Home.aspx"/>
 </appSettings>


 Response.Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PersonalDetails "].ToString() + "?Id=" + 1, false);
```